# Java: Why isn't this JFrame button displaying?

Tags: java, swing

Basically, all i wan't is for this button to display. It was working in another program I had earlier but it doesn't seem to be working in this one and i have no idea why. If anyone could help that would be great.

```
public void fixtureList()
{
    JButton editButton;

    setLayout(null);

    editButton = new JButton("Edit");
    editButton.setBounds(200, 200, 100, 100);
    add(editButton);

}

public void loginPanel()
{
    setLayout(null);

    JButton loginButton;

    loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    loginButton.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
    add(loginButton);
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            fixtureList();
            System.out.println("Loading the fixtures screen");
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to call `loginPanel()`. Try:

```
    Main window = new Main();

    window.setTitle("PE Fixtures v1.0");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.loginPanel();
    window.setSize(250, 430);
    window.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(53, 56, 64));
    window.setVisible(true);
```

Although, because you are subclassing `JFrame`, I would suggest doing most of that work in the constructor.

Comment: Ok, that worked brilliant, and if i added an event handler to the button and had it load another function named "fixtures" that'd work right?

Comment: If I'm understanding that correctly, yeah it would.

Comment: Ok, if you look at the main question i edited the code. It should display another button when "Login" is pressed but it doesn't display the button.

Comment: It's because you are setting the layout twice. When you change layouts, it removes all components of that layout. In your `fixtureList()` method, remove `setLayout(null);`

Comment: It displays the "System.out.println" but not the button?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call loginPanel() method within your main method, it is not being used at the moment.

Comment: That wouldn't be entirely correct because `JFrame` isn't an `instanceof` `Main`. But, `Main` is an `instanceof` `JFrame`. Therefore, because he is declaring his window as a `JFrame` (instead of `Main`), the `loginPanel()` method doesn't even exist.